# arithmetic operation on list::iterator?

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, stl-algorithm

I got a `list` like this:

```
list<float> l;
```

And I know there are 10 elements in `l`, I want to take first 7 elements from `l` and assign them to a `vector`, so I tried to do it like this:

```
vector<float> v(l.begin(), l.begin()+7);
```

The code above can't compile, later I found out that, `list` doesn't support **random access** while `vector` does, so `list::iterator` doesn't support arithmetic operation?

If so, How could I finish the job mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use copy_n:

```
v.resize(7);
copy_n(l.begin(), 7, v.begin());
```

Comment: I guess, the `back_inserter` could be used to resize `v`, right?

Comment: I'm not using C++11 at present, can I use `copy_n`?

Comment: @Alcott Yes: `copy_n(l.begin(), 7, back_inserter(v));`

Comment: @Peter v needs to be empty to use back_inserter(v), otherwise use v.begin() to overwrite v's contents. Right ?

Comment: @Alcott back_inserter will not resize v.  Refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/

Comment: @hotadvice, AFAIK, `back_inserter` will invoke the container's `push_back` method which will change the container's size.

Comment: Well, `<algorithm>` included, code with `copy_n` doesn't compile with g++, either. Is `copy_n` a C++11 thing?

Comment: back_inserter will be slower than resize + copy_n because copy_n don't check the size of the container. And copy_n will also check whether the copy can be optimized by using memcpy, if it is, memcpy will be called rather than one-by-one copy.

Comment: @user956030, and `copy_n` is a c++11 thing, isn't it?

Comment: @user956030, any idea how to it in VC6.0?

Comment: you can try [stlport](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/) or [sgi stl](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)

Comment: @Alcott Sorry, I was replying to your first question, rather than the second about C++11. No, you can't use `copy_n` without some implementation of C++11. You could always write your own `copy_n`, it's not difficult.